# TCP connection existing on server/client during TIME_WAIT state

Tags: tcp

A simple question:

When the connection reaches the TIME_WAIT state on the client, does the connection still exist on the server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The connection reaches the TIME_WAIT state when both peers have closed their sockets. It doesn't exist for any practical purpose except timing out the TIME_WAIT state.

Answer (score -1):

The presence of many TIME-WAIT TCBs can increases the demultiplexing time for active connections.

The design of TCP places the TIME-WAIT TCB at the endpoint that closes the connection; this decision conflicts with the semantics of many application protocols. The File Transfer Protocol (FTP) and HTTP both interpret the closing of the transport connection as an end-of-transaction marker. In each case, the application protocol requires that servers close the transport connection, and the transport protocol requires that servers incur a memory cost if they do. Protocols that use other methods of marking end-of-transaction, e.g., SUN RPC over TCP, can have the clients close connections at the expense of a more complex application protocol.

As networks become faster and support more users, the connection rates at busy servers are likely to increase, resulting in more TIME-WAIT loading. 
Intuitively, the first endpoint to close a connection closes it actively, and the second passively; HTTP and FTP servers generally close connections actively.

Comment: Very nice but you haven't answered the question.

Comment: The answer is already there , the connection is not exist anymore in many reasons except  TIME_WAIT but it can be establish a new connection as per requirement.